# How to find the number of ways to get 21 in Blackjack?

Tags: python, oop, combinations, blackjack, playing-cards

Some assumptions:

1. One deck of 52 cards is used
2. Picture cards count as 10
3. Aces count as 1 or 11
4. The order is not important (ie. Ace + Queen is the same as Queen + Ace)

I thought I would then just sequentially try all the possible combinations and see which ones add up to 21, but there are way too many ways to mix the cards (52! ways). This approach also does not take into account that order is not important nor does it account for the fact that there are only 4 maximum types of any one card (Spade, Club, Diamond, Heart).

Now I am thinking of the problem like this:

We have 11 "slots". Each of these slots can have 53 possible things inside them: 1 of 52 cards or no card at all. The reason it is 11 slots is because 11 cards is the maximum amount of cards that can be dealt and still add up to 21; more than 11 cards would have to add up to more than 21.

Then the "leftmost" slot would be incremented up by one and all 11 slots would be checked to see if they add up to 21 (0 would represent no card in the slot). If not, the next slot to the right would be incremented, and the next, and so on.

Once the first 4 slots contain the same "card" (after four increments, the first 4 slots would all be 1), the fifth slot could not be that number as well since there are 4 numbers of any type. The fifth slot would then become the next lowest number in the remaining available cards; in the case of four 1s, the fifth slot would become a 2 and so on.

How would you do approach this?

Comment: There are a ton of different ways to go about this. A suggestion: store all 52 card values [1,1,1,1,2,2,... 10,10] in a single array so you don't have to worry about "only 4 of a certain value" anywhere else. Then unique hands can be represented by indexes into that array. Note - There are probably even better ways to think about this...

Comment: Do you mean picture cards count as 10? or picture cards count as 0?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet - picture cards are worth 10 in a game of 21...

Comment: @Krease I could have sworn it said 0 before.

Comment: Thinking about this further, having aces represent 1 OR 11 complicates matters somewhat, so my suggestion above would need changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before worrying about the suits and different cards with value `10` lets figure out how many different value combinations resulting to `21` there are. For example `5, 5, 10, 1` is one such combination. The following function takes in `limit` which is the target value, `start` which indicates the lowest value that can be picked and `used` which is the list of picked values:

```
def combinations(limit, start, used):
    # Base case
    if limit == 0:
        return 1

    # Start iteration from lowest card to picked so far
    # so that we're only going to pick cards 3 & 7 in order 3,7
    res = 0
    for i in range(start, min(12, limit + 1)):
        # Aces are at index 1 no matter if value 11 or 1 is used
        index = i if i != 11 else 1

        # There are 16 cards with value of 10 (T, J, Q, K) and 4 with every
        # other value
        available = 16 if index == 10 else 4
        if used[index] < available:
            # Mark the card used and go through combinations starting from
            # current card and limit lowered by the value
            used[index] += 1
            res += combinations(limit - i, i, used)
            used[index] -= 1

    return res

print combinations(21, 1, [0] * 11) # 416
```

Since we're interested about different card combinations instead of different value combinations the base case in above should be modified to return number of different card combinations that can be used to generate a value combination. Luckily that's quite easy task, [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) can be used to figure out how many different combinations of `k` items can be picked from `n` items.

Once the number of different card combinations for each value in `used` is known they can be just multiplied with each other for the final result. So for the example of `5, 5, 10, 1` value `5` results to `bcoef(4, 2) == 6`, value `10` to `bcoef(16, 1) == 16` and value `1` to `bcoef(4, 1) == 4`. For all the other values `bcoef(x, 0)` results to `1`. Multiplying those values results to `6 * 16 * 4 == 384` which is then returned:

```
import operator
from math import factorial

def bcoef(n, k):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))

def combinations(limit, start, used):
    if limit == 0:
        combs = (bcoef(4 if i != 10 else 16, x) for i, x in enumerate(used))
        res = reduce(operator.mul, combs, 1)
        return res

    res = 0
    for i in range(start, min(12, limit + 1)):
        index = i if i != 11 else 1
        available = 16 if index == 10 else 4

        if used[index] < available:
            used[index] += 1
            res += combinations(limit - i, i, used)
            used[index] -= 1

    return res

print combinations(21, 1, [0] * 11) # 186184
```

Comment: @Kos I've extended the answer to cover the scenario where cards with face value of 10 and suits are considered different. Unfortunately I couldn't find a source which would verify the results I've come up with though,

Comment: Does this include the fact that ace can be either an 11 or a 1 ?

Comment: @Kos Yes it does,the minimum value for `i` in the loop is `1` (=ace considered as 1) and the max is `11` (=ace considered as 11). No matter which value ace is considered it is still marked as used the same way (in `used[1]`).

Comment: Your answer comes very close to the the actual. I iterated through every possible combination, (see my answer below), and it comes out to be 188052 vs your number of 186184. So it seems like you're missing about 2000. I want to use your algorithm because it's much faster. but I want to see where the 2000 got lost. How can I check the count if I want to try 3 cards only, then 4 cards only, etc.

Comment: @Joe: In `for i in range(start, 12):` constant dictates what values are considered and `if used[index] < 4:` defines that there are 4 cards per each value. Ace is always at `index[1]`.  Value of 10 has of course 16 slots but I didn't bother coding it there since the upper limit 21 so you can use max two cards of point value of 10. If you want to do experiments here's what you can do: pass in lower `limit` to function, lower the constants mentioned mentioned earlier & remove special handling of ace or lower the alternative value from 11.

Comment: @niemmi ... okay, I accept your answer as correct. Even if it weren't, you could easily tweak it. The excellent thing about your algorithm is that you solve counting problems of probability in less than a second. So thanks for sharing your approach. When I have time, I am going to try to see how to generate the solution set from your approach.

Answer (score 3):

divide and conquer by leveraging the knowledge that if you have 13 and pick a 10 you only have to pick cards to sum to 3 left to look at ... be forwarned this solution might be slow(took about 180 seconds on my box... it is definately non-optimal) ..

```
def sum_to(x,cards):
    if x == 0: # if there is nothing left to sum to
        yield []

    for i in range(1,12): # for each point value 1..11 (inclusive)
        if i  > x: break # if i is bigger than whats left we are done
        card_v = 11 if i == 1 else i
        if card_v not in cards: continue  # if there is no more of this card
        new_deck = cards[:] # create a copy of hte deck (we do not want to modify the original)
        if i == 1: # one is clearly an ace...
           new_deck.remove(11)
        else: # remove the value
           new_deck.remove(i)
        # on the recursive call we need to subtract our recent pick
        for result in sum_to(x-i,new_deck):
            yield [i] + result # append each further combination to our solutions
```

set up your cards as follows

```
deck = []
for i in range(2,11): # two through ten (with 4 of each)
    deck.extend([i]*4)

deck.extend([10]*4) #jacks
deck.extend([10]*4) #queens
deck.extend([10]*4) #kings
deck.extend([11]*4) # Aces
```

then just call your function

```
for combination in sum_to(21,deck):
    print combination
```

unfortunately this does allow some duplicates to sneak in ... 
in order to get unique entries you need to change it a little bit

in `sum_to` on the last line change it to

```
  # sort our solutions so we can later eliminate duplicates
  yield sorted([i] + result) # append each further combination to our solutions
```

then when you get your combinations you gotta do some deep dark voodoo style python

```
 unique_combinations = sorted(set(map(tuple,sum_to(21,deck))),key=len,reverse=0)

 for combo in unique_combinations: print combo
```

from this cool question i have learned the following (keep in mind in real play you would have the dealer and other players also removing from the same deck)

```
there are 416 unique combinations of a deck of cards that make 21
there are 300433 non-unique combinations!!!

the longest number of ways to make 21 are as follows
with 11 cards there are 1 ways
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)]
with 10 cards there are 7 ways
with 9 cards there are 26 ways
with 8 cards there are 54 ways
with 7 cards there are 84 ways
with 6 cards there are 94 ways
with 5 cards there are 83 ways
with 4 cards there are 49 ways
with 3 cards there are 17 ways
with 2 cards there are 1 ways
[(10, 11)]

there are 54 ways in which all 4 aces are used in making 21!!
there are 106 ways of making 21 in which NO aces are used !!!
```

keep in mind these are often suboptimal plays (ie considering A,10 -> 1,10 and hitting )

Comment: How does this handle aces being 1 or 11?

Comment: "from this cool question I have learned...". Totally agree. First, the question is awesome. Second,  I always learn something new when trying to solve questions that are asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: lol i spent a loong time already on this answer ... perhaps tomorrow I can help further for that case

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to write the script that every possible viable hand can be checked. The total number comes out to be 188052. Since I checked every possible combination, this is the exact number (as opposed to an estimate):

```
import itertools as it
big_list = []

def deck_set_up(m):
    special = {8:'a23456789TJQK', 9:'a23456789', 10:'a2345678', 11:'a23'} 
    if m in special:
        return [x+y for x,y in list(it.product(special[m], 'shdc'))]
    else:
        return [x+y for x,y in list(it.product('a23456789TJQKA', 'shdc'))]

deck_dict = {'as':1,'ah':1,'ad':1,'ac':1,
             '2s':2,'2h':2,'2d':2,'2c':2,
             '3s':3,'3h':3,'3d':3,'3c':3,
             '4s':4,'4h':4,'4d':4,'4c':4,
             '5s':5,'5h':5,'5d':5,'5c':5,
             '6s':6,'6h':6,'6d':6,'6c':6,
             '7s':7,'7h':7,'7d':7,'7c':7,
             '8s':8,'8h':8,'8d':8,'8c':8,
             '9s':9,'9h':9,'9d':9,'9c':9,
             'Ts':10,'Th':10,'Td':10,'Tc':10,
             'Js':10,'Jh':10,'Jd':10,'Jc':10,
             'Qs':10,'Qh':10,'Qd':10,'Qc':10,
             'Ks':10,'Kh':10,'Kd':10,'Kc':10,
             'As':11,'Ah':11,'Ad':11,'Ac':11}

stop_here = {2:'As', 3:'8s', 4:'6s', 5:'4h', 6:'3c', 7:'3s', 8:'2h', 9:'2s', 10:'2s', 11:'2s'}

for n in range(2,12):  # n is number of cards in the draw
    combos = it.combinations(deck_set_up(n), n)
    stop_point = stop_here[n]
    while True:
        try:
            pick = combos.next()
        except:
            break
        if pick[0] == stop_point:
            break                   
        if n < 8:
            if len(set([item.upper() for item in pick])) != n:
                continue
        if sum([deck_dict[card] for card in pick]) == 21:
            big_list.append(pick)
    print n, len(big_list)  # Total number hands that can equal 21 is 188052
```

In the output, the the first column is the number of cards in the draw, and the second number is the cumulative count. So the number after "3" in the output is the total count of hands that equal 21 for a 2-card draw, and a 3-card draw. The lower case a is a low ace (1 point), and uppercase A is high ace. I have a line (the one with the set command), to make sure it throws out any hand that has a duplicate card.

The script takes 36 minutes to run. So there is definitely a trade-off between execution time, and accuracy. The "big_list" contains the solutions (i.e. every hand where the sum is 21)

```
>>> 
================== RESTART: C:\Users\JBM\Desktop\bj3.py     ==================
2 64
3 2100
4 14804
5 53296
6 111776
7 160132
8 182452
9 187616
10 188048
11 188052    # <-- This is the total count, as these numbers are cumulative
>>>
```

Comment: I just checked the code and the differences in results might be explained by the fact that you have 2 different cards for each ace. You could do an experiment where you convert `ah` to `Ah` in the `pick`, convert `pick` to `frozenset` and change the type of `biglist` to a `set`. That would ensure that you consider aces the same and you have no duplicate picks.

Comment: Made the changes I explained above and ran the code, the end result was 186184 which matches my solution.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip on frozenset. I haven'd used that before. It's amazing you were able to understand my code. I put in all those hacks (modified decks, stopping point, etc) to make it run faster. I was able to cut execution time from 9 hours to about 30 minutes, but now my code is practically unreadable. I'll try your frozen set experiment